# redirect to another page, if the MySQL statement returns an empty result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

am working on reports and currently have a problem with how the output should be when and if the MySQL statement returns an empty result. i have two problems i.e 1) i need to use the WHILE statement to give all possible results when query is true. 2) i think an ELSE statement needs to be used to redirect me to another page if the result is false. Now i have noticed that WHILE and ELSE statements cannot be used together in that way. correct me if am wrong. again if am to use IF where there is WHILE, the output will be limited to only one record.

```
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>Messages Received</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                  <h1 align="center">Messeges Received</h1>
                  <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
                    <div align="center">
                    <table width="700" border="1" >
                      <tr style="background:#093; color:#FFF; font-weight:bold">
                        <td width="150">Name</td>
                        <td width="180">Email/User_ID</td>
                        <td width="174">Subject</td>
                        <td width="168">Date Received</td>
                        </tr>


                          <?php  
            include("connect.php");
            mysql_select_db("ceec", $con);

            $query = "SELECT * FROM messeges ORDER BY date DESC";

            $result=mysql_query($query);

            while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

                        $id=$row['id'];
                        $date = date("D d M, Y", strtotime($row['date']));
                echo '
                 <tr>
                    <td>'. $row["name"] .'</td>
                    <td>'. $row["email"] .'</td>
                    <td>'. $row["sub"] .'</td>
                    <td>'. $date .'</td>
                  </tr>';
            }
            else
            {
            header("Location: no_sms.php");
            }   

            ?>
             </table>

            </form>
           </body>
           </html>
```

Comment: where you use if condition ??????

Comment: if (!empty($result)){ code }else{ redirect page code ; }

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM messeges ORDER BY date DESC";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!empty($result)) {

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $id = $row['id'];
        $date = date("D d M, Y", strtotime($row['date']));

        echo '
             <tr>
                <td>' . $row["name"] . '</td>
                <td>' . $row["email"] . '</td>
                <td>' . $row["sub"] . '</td>
                <td>' . $date . '</td>
              </tr>';
    }
    //while end
} //if end 

else {
    header("Location: no_sms.php");
}

?>
```

Comment: buddy! this doesn't redirect me to no_sms.php instead it outputs an empty table with the specified headers only, when the result is empty. in other words it doesn't have any affect.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result=mysql_query($query);

//This Will Direct Redirect If Result Set Is Empty

if(empty($result)){

  header("Location: no_sms.php");

}

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

  $id=$row['id'];

  $date = date("D d M, Y", strtotime($row['date']));

  echo '
  <tr>
   <td>'. $row["name"] .'</td>
    <td>'. $row["email"] .'</td>
     <td>'. $row["sub"] .'</td>
     <td>'. $date .'</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

Comment: on second try/testing, i have realised that this code gives respect to no_sms.php. such that regardless of the result it redirects to no_sms.php. please revisit. my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this its working :**

```
     <html>
                <head>
                <title>Messages Received</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                      <h1 align="center">Messeges Received</h1>
                      <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
                        <div align="center">
                        <table width="700" border="1" >
                          <tr style="background:#093; color:#FFF; font-weight:bold">
                            <td width="150">Name</td>
                            <td width="180">Email/User_ID</td>
                            <td width="174">Subject</td>
                            <td width="168">Date Received</td>
                            </tr>


                              <?php  
                include("connect.php");
                mysql_select_db("ceec", $con);

                $query = "SELECT * FROM messeges ORDER BY date DESC";

                $result=mysql_query($query);

              $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

       if(!empty($row)) {
         do {
                    echo '
                     <tr>
                        <td>'. $row["name"] .'</td>
                        <td>'. $row["email"] .'</td>
                        <td>'. $row["sub"] .'</td>
                        <td>'. $date .'</td>
                      </tr>';
                }while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result));
}
                else
                {
                header("Location: no_sms.php");
                }   

                ?>
                 </table>

                </form>
               </body>
               </html>
```

Comment: @mountain now check and thank you for correcting me.

Comment: this doesn't redirect me to no_sms.php instead it outputs an empty table with the specified headers only, when the result is empty. in other words it doesn't have any effect. lets keep cracking our brains buddy.

Comment: @mountain : Now finally this code is working try it again. I changed in code.

Comment: it works but with one big problem. it only outputs one record when the result is true. please read my above problem statement in my question. lets keep working buddy

Comment: @ Rohit Jindal wow! you the man. perfect! everything is working just as i wanted. please email me on mountainclimbing1@gmail.com

Comment: thanks! i have the code. just want more stuff from you on a personal level

Comment: please send me an email.

Comment: @mountain what type of stuff you want from me ? first tick this answer bro. It will be useful for others also.